# Find files that would be changed by git cherry

Tags: git, git-cherry

According to its man page, `git cherry` does some testing to determine if a commit should be cherry picked into another branch:

```
The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace
and line numbers. git-cherry therefore detects when commits have been
"copied" by means of git-cherry-pick(1), git-am(1) or git-rebase(1).
```

I want create a script to further minimize the list of cherry-pick candidates by removing all commits that would change only a certain file.

E.g. if cherry picking commit 1 with changed files A, B, C into my branch would change only file A while B and C would already contain the changes, I want the script to remove the commit from the list of candidates.

To put it another way, if I cherry-picked a commit as suggested by `git cherry`, and the resulting commit would change only file A, and no other files, I would want to remove it from my list.

Is there an easy way to get this information out of Git?

Comment: Could you explain more about what your workflow is, and why cherry-picking is such a common occurence you want to do it en-masse with a script?

Comment: The possibility of conflicts, and of reverts in the upstream makes it hard to answer -- if a cherry-pick has been applied and subsequently reverted or amended, `git cherry` will still show it as having been applied, since it has, but the upstream tip no longer has the result, so cherry-picking it again would change the file, and that might be what you want or might not. What do you want listed in those cases?

Comment: Note that we're assuming you mean *would be changed by cherry-pick*, not *would be changed by cherry*, because `git cherry` merely prints out commits. It never updates anything.

Answer (score 1):

> further minimize the list of cherry-pick candidates by removing all commits that would change only a certain file

You can use `git diff-tree -p $commit | git apply --exclude=path/to/that/file --numstat`, if that lists any changes, the commit has changes in other files, but it's not clear what "would change" means here.  "Would change", if you cherry-picked it again regardless of whether its changes outside that file have already been applied?

The only way to do that is to do a test run of the actual apply. You can automate that check, but you're leaving a lot of questions open here.  `git diff-tree -p $commit | git apply --exclude=path/to/that/file -3`, then `git diff --name-only` to see if there's any changes pending, then `git reset --hard` before doing or not doing the whole cherry-pick.

But cherry-picking a commit could make changes to the current upstream tip *regardless of whether it's already been cherry-picked*, if subsequent work reverted it or amended it. So if you don't care whether you're re-applying subsequently reverted changes, why are you starting from the `git cherry` list at all?  Something isn't making sense here.

Answer (score 0):

(depending on how you interpret "easy" ...)

`git` has a [`patch-id` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) command, that builds a hash from a diff, with some rules (ignoring line numbers and whitespaces) to try to have the property : two patches that introduce the same changes will have the same patch-id.

You can use this in the following way :

for each commit :

1. choose a way to generate the patch it produces on files other than `that/file`
2. run that patch through `| git patch-id --stable`
3. once you have computed all patch-ids in your range of commits, you can compare them to prune commits from your list